# I'm trying to creat and store a file locally in my pc using any web programing language

Tags: php

I'm trying to save a txt file in my pc locally with php, but not in the download folder. I need to add in different folder.

Here is my code

```
$txt = "$dirname/Contact.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+');
exit();

fwrite($fh,$txt);
close($fh);
```

Comment: Take a look at Electron.

Comment: Remove the `exit()` that STOPS EXECUTION

Comment: WHERE is the javascript in this question to warrent the TAG. PLease dont SPAM Tags

Comment: WHERE is the HTML in this question to warrent the HTML tag? Please dont spam tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER` variable to specify your path

`$myTxt = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "you/path/directory"`

But remember that the path first is in your project, you may go out with `"../"`

And your `exit();` command, this kills your code. Put this at the end of the file. It will never reaches `close($fh);`

Maybe only fixing this `exit();` will solve your problem.